# Is there a way to programmatically handle malformed rows using CsvProvider?

Tags: f#, f#-data

Is there a way using `CsvProvider` to inject in code which attempts to generate valid values for a malformed row?  `CsgProvider<IgnoreErrors=true>` will skip any malformed row but the data is lost.

For a specific example CsvProvider failes on row 679644 of the IMDB movie titles, a very clean 9 column tab delimited file, with an error about unexpected columns detected.  In this case the double quotes seem to be the issue as changing them to another character allows the line to be successfully parsed.

```
type Movies = CsvProvider< @"c:\title.sample.tsv", MissingValues="\N", CacheRows=false,
                           Schema="string,string,string,string,boolean, int option, int option, int option, string",
                           IgnoreErrors=false >
let getMovies path =
    use file = File.OpenRead(path)
    use reader = new StreamReader(file)
    let movies = Movies.Load(reader)
    movies.Filter(fun r -> r.TitleType = "movie").Rows
    |> Seq.toArray

getMovies @"c:\title.basics.20171218.tsv"
|> Seq.iter (fun t-> printfn "%A" t)
```

**Data Slice**

```
tt0701219   tvEpisode   Summer of 4'2"  Summer of 4'2"  0   1996    \N  30  Animation,Comedy
tt0701220   tvEpisode   Sunday, Cruddy Sunday   Sunday, Cruddy Sunday   0   1999    \N  30  Animation,Comedy
tt0701221   tvEpisode   Sweets and Sour Marge   Sweets and Sour Marge   0   2002    \N  30  Animation,Comedy
tt0701222   tvEpisode   Take My Wife, Sleaze    Take My Wife, Sleaze    0   1999    \N  30  Animation,Comedy
tt0701223   tvEpisode   Tennis the Menace   Tennis the Menace   0   2001    \N  30  Animation,Comedy
tt0701224   tvEpisode   Thank God It's Doomsday Thank God It's Doomsday 0   2005    \N  30  Animation,Comedy
```

What I am trying to determine is whether there is a hook in the CsvProvider to allow for the consumer to inject in code to help parse a row that is being read out of the source file.

Comment: What do you mean by "coerce"? The question is not clear, and the context is not clear.

Comment: By coerce I mean to take a malformed value and through code generate a valid value.

Comment: This is not `CsvProvider` per se, but you could use [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/) to parse your file. It has options to save malformed data, and also custom event handlers. But I agree with the comment above, could you at least show some specific example with malformed data and the output you expect?

Comment: @s952163 Thank you for the suggestion about FileHelpers but I am attempting to learn how to best leverage the F# type providers.

Comment: You could try using the [`Quote`](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/reference/fsharp-data-csvprovider.html) parameter (i.e. try setting it to something else than "), or alternatively use the [Csv Parser](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvFile.html). Generally type providers assume your data is well structured, in many cases for delimited files that's not the case, hence my suggestion above.

Comment: Why not transform the data source before running it through your loading process? A standard procedure is known as ETL. Extract, Transform, Load. So in this case Transform would mean creating a copy where you replace all double quotes with single quotes using any utility you like. A small Unix script could do this or any decent text editor (some of which allow macros).

Comment: @s952163 `CsvFile` appears to be a bit more tolerant but ultimately either parses the whole file successfully or excludes failing rows. This makes sense the docs call it out as the core implementation of `CsvProvider`.  If you want to answer my question that there is no hook to manipulate the data I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy Yes the question is about the T in ETL.  The CvsProvider is handing the L.  I am attempting to fix the data as it is being ingested which is a far preferable approach then a multi-pass solution.